# сессии и веб сокет

Tags: php

Подскажите, возможно ли использовать сессии и ratchet ? Или быть может есть вебсокеты с поддержкой сессий..или вообще направьте на путь истинный. Через Ratchet сделал чат, оформил и т.п.. Однако встал вопрос о валидации передаваемого идентификатора сессии. Дело в том, что на клиенте его можно подменить и отправить в обработчик соответственно. Ну и вот чтоб этого избежать хотелось сравнивать с сессией пользователя, который и отправил сообщение..если расхождение, то вывести ошибочку.

Comment: так храните его в базе какой-нибудь.. Записывайте токен + expiration time, и сравнивайте время с текущим когда надо узнать жива сессия или нет

Comment: @InDevX а если посредством пхп зашифровать (своим, придуманным алгоритмом) значение из сессии, вставить результат в переменную JS и отправлять от клиента вместе с сообщением на обработчик, там дешифровывать переменную и сверять..имеет место быть ?

Comment: Имеет место, имеет. Но так сессия бесконечная получается. Так-то, можно просто jwt юзать и туда время жизни добавлять.

Comment: @InDevX почему..если доступ в чат имеют только авторизованные юзеры, то для авторизованных и шифровать сессию..соответственно, когда разлогинется или истечет срок жизни сессии - шифроваться будет нечему..или я неправильно понимаю

Comment: посмотрите JWT.